# How to add a score to a Tic Tac Toe Game

Tags: objective-c

I am struggling to implement a score on my tic tac toe game. I am new to Xcode so don't understand everything. Below is my "if user wins code" any help is appreciated !!

```
   if([self checkforwin]){
        NSString*winner = nil;
        if (playertoken==1)winner=@"Player 2 Wins";
         else if (playertoken==2)winner= @"Player 1 Wins";
       score ++;
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Result"
                              message: winner
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [self resetboard];
        [_audioPlayer play];
        [alert show];
    }
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: I am new to Xcode and have a question about adding a score on my tic tac toe. I don't know what to add to make the score be +1 on the app if you win the round. @BryanChen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not into objective-c but you have to make one score for each player etc. score2 and score1.

So:

```
        if (playertoken==1){
               winner=@"Player 2 Wins";
               score1 ++;
}
        else if (playertoken==2){
            winner= @"Player 1 Wins";
            score2 ++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. I am still having errors within the code which I can't understand which are Arithmetic UIlabel is to big for the architecture